# Android get contentView id

Tags: android, view

Now I develop android and I want to get `viewId`.

For example:

```
onCreate(){
     setContentView(R.layout.a) 
     button bt1 = findViewId(R.id.bt); 
     bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{    });
}
```

So now, I want to get view Id in `onClickListener`. I think, view Id
 same `R.layout.content` and I try to `findViewId(R.id.content)` but
 this viewid is different from `R.layout.a` how can I get viewId?

Answer (score 2):

your id is here:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int yourid =  v.getId()    
}
```

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi , 10x. copy-pasted from my code. fixed

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.viewid:
        {           
            break;
        }
        case R.id.viewid:
        {

            break;
        }
        default :
        {          
            break;
   }


    }
```